# How does one add a reference to Microsoft.SharePoint.dll

Tags: sharepoint-online, autohosted

I've been trying to use the `SPGridView` control, which I've seen in quite a few examples around the web. This control is contained in the `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls` namespace which is in the Microsoft.SharePoint dll. But this dll does not appear in my list of available references in Visual Studio 2013.

I have the Office Developer Tools installed, so is there any other package I need to get this library? I'm developing for SharePoint Online, so I don't have a local SharePoint environment (some other forum posts suggested copying this library off of the SharePoint server). If it's not a library, how would I go about getting hold of this binary?

Any & all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In visual studio 2013 try : Add reference -> assemblies -> framwork 4.5 dll. Search for sharepoint. I hope you might get there.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The closest I see is Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, which I already have a reference to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only use that DLL in a farm solution, which requires development on a SharePoint server.  You will need to use a plain old asp.net GridView for what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation, this was driving me insane. Just to follow on from this, would it then be possible to style my GridView to look like a SharePoint grid then? Otherwise this grid will be the only one that looks different...

Comment: Yeah, you'll want to look into a standard SharePoint list view or whatever and inspect its structure and CSS classes, and do the same inside your GridView's template.

Answer (score 2):

For SharePoint Online you can only use Microsoft.SharePoint.Client