# Which library do I have to include to use SPListItem in VBA?

Tags: 2013, excel, vba

I want to read and modifiy SharePoint Lists with `VBA` from within `Microsoft Excel 2013`.

Unfortunately I can not find which library I have to include to use those commands like described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460222/check-in-and-check-out-in-spfile-object

Comment: `SPListItem` is residing in the Micosoft.SharePoint.dll, you probably need to add it as a reference in your project. the file can be found on the Server: "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\"

Comment: thanks, that does already help. However that means if I do not have access to the server, I also can't get a copy of the DLL? An answer in another thread (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/101863/19145 ) says, that this DLL can only be used for development on a Farm solution, but I'm just working on a SharePoint Client...

Comment: well, if you just need the client assemblies, you should be able to get them [there](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585). after installing those and creating a sharepoint project in studio you should be able to add the references to ms.sp.client and client runtime by selecting from the list of framework extensions. For further details see: [Creating Basic SP Client Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539974(v=office.15).aspx)